# Why does my FORM get submitted after an Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following:

```
<form id="form" action="xxx" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb">
  <button onclick="update();">Update</button>
</form>

<script>
  function update() {
    var data = $("#form").serialize();
    $.ajax( {
      url: "/api/m/x",
      type: "post",
      data: data
      }
     ).done(function(results,status) {
          alert(status);
       }).fail(function(error, status) {
          alert(status);
      });
   }
</script>
```

When I clicked the Update button, the Ajax call was made to `/api/m/x` and one of the alerts was triggered. So far so good.  However, after I closed the alert dialog, the form is submitted!  The browser is sent to `xxx?cb=on`, for example if I ticked the check box.

Why is this happening? My form does not have an `<input type='submit'>` element. Who is triggering the submit of the form?

I tried adding `return false;` to the `update` function but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: where is your success

Comment: That's in the `done` right?

Comment: Because you're doing nothing to stop it from being submitted

Comment: try <button type=button>Submit</button>

Comment: Is there a reason why you have using inline handler? Also, you need to see the handler as the equivalent of `function(){update()}` and that should tell you why `return false;` in the `update` function is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<button>` tag in a form is a submit button unless you specify `type=button`
Also the return false should be on the `onsubmit` event

```
<form id="form" action="xxx" method="get" onsubmit="return update();">

function update() {
...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have button in form, form is submitting when you click this button

try like this:

```
<form onsubmit="update();return false;">
```